# How to populate the dropdown which is in the user control based on value selection of other dropdown in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the scenario-

I have a `dropdown` on aspx page. Based on the selection of value in the `dropdown`,I want to populate the values of `dropdown` which is in my `USER CONTROL (ascx)`.How should i do it?

Please help with sample example.

Thanks

Comment: Show your work and tell people what have you tried and what is the problem exactly.

Comment: you must learn basics of webusercontrol first. it will be helpful to you.

Comment: If a dropdown in your aspx page influences the dropdown in your webuser control, shouldn't you consider to make one user control with both the dropdowns? That makes more logical sense.
If that isn't an option I'd put the value of the first dropdown in my session and do auto postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your usercontrol create property:

```
public object DataSource
{
    set{
        ddl.DataSource = value; 
        ddl.Databind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---", "0"));
    }
}
```

In parent page where is located first `DropDownList` (don't forget to set `AutoPostback=true` and add event `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_OnSelectedIndexChanged"` for this `DropDownList`):

```
protected void ddl_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList )sender;
    var _dataSource=/// some logic That will fill the datasource object by condition
    // for example 
    // _dataSource=listofObject.Where(ob=>ob.Value.Equals(ddl.SelectedValue)).ToList();
    yourControl.DataSource=_dataSource;
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply.But no luck. I will give some more details about my problem. When user selects value in dropdown which is in parent page, with the help of this value i want to populate the dropdown which is in ascx page.

Comment: Hi I used above code but its throwing object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @user2405121 Do you fill _datasource variable with any values from database or some List of object?

Comment: current = new AccountController().FetchByQuery( new SubSonic.Query(Account.Schema) .WHERE("AccountGroup_id", selectedAccountGroup.ID)); like this

Comment: in dropdownlist what is in ascx control you should define property value="<fieldNameIndatabase>" and text="<fieldnameindatabase>"

Comment: current = new AccountController().FetchByQuery( new SubSonic.Query(Account.Schema) .WHERE("AccountGroup_id", ddl.SelecteValue)); if AccountGroup_id is field from first ddl

Comment: HI...not getting what you are trying to say. I am getting values from database correctly. Dropdown in ascx page is throwing this error-->Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: If I understand correct variable current has to contain values for dropdownlist what is in ascx control

Comment: yes you are correct...variable current has values for dropdown which is in ascx and I am defiining current in Parent page and passing it to ascx with the help of your code..but not able to assign]

Comment: var current = new AccountController().FetchByQuery( new SubSonic.Query(Account.Schema) .WHERE("AccountGroup_id", ddl.SelecteValue)).ToList();  yourControl.DataSource=current;

Comment: ya i have used this only but no luck

Comment: Yes, This is value of controlID what you defined in aspx file

Comment: and ddl in Datasource property is name of your dropdown list in ascx control

Comment: FetchByQuery().ExectueAsCollection<T>()

Comment: Does new AccountController().FetchByQuery( new SubSonic.Query(Account.Schema) .WHERE("AccountGroup_id", ddl.SelecteValue) return of any values?

Comment: And first dropdownlist you have to populate only one time:  if(!Page.IsPostBack) ddl.DataSource=list; ddl.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

Create public `DropDownList` property in user control and fill it in `Page_Load` by pages `DropDownList` control. Than you will have access to pages control.

Comment: Thanks but can you give some example.